# Erros: Failed to download module - Azure DevOps Pipeline

Tags: azure-devops, terraform, azure-pipelines, azure-repos

I have a terraform overarching script in which 5 different terraform modules are defined and integrated together. The overarching script and the 5 modules are saved in different Azure DevOps repositories. When I run the overarching script (terraform init and apply) from vs code, everything is working fine. But when I make terraform init and apply run through Azure DevOps Pipeline, I get an error saying "Failed to download module". As far as I can understand, it is a Host Key Verification failure. Can someone please help me with this :')

This is how the overarching script looks like: [Overarching script - main.tf] [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ALGk0.png

And this the Pipeline YAML Script:

```
    - script: |
        terraform init
    - script: |
        terraform plan
      displayName: 'Terraform Plan'
```

and this is the example of the error that I get:

[Pipeline Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GQ4BP.png)

Comment: Please paste the code and the errors as plain text (with formatting) instead of adding screenshots.